# How to hide the end of a string after a certain character, with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

I have a string that will sometimes include a hyphen (-) and sometimes won't. When the string contains a hyphen, I want to remove or hide the hyphen and any text that comes after it.

For instance, 'john' would be rendered 'john'. And 'john-hops-over-the-candlestick' would also be rendered 'john'.

Comment: Wow, several good answers have come in immediately. Not sure how to choose the best, but I'll choose in a minute here. I've also realized I need to loop through the elements with jquery and then run this routine on each via jquery's text() method.

Comment: OK, many of the answers could've worked, and I went with the regex in my jquery, as follows: `$( "span.first-name").each(function() {  
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/-.*$/, ''));        
    });`

Comment: I like these types of questions, where the problem isn't necessarily difficult to solve, but you get a lot of interesting different approaches that accomplish the same thing. (Well, the answers that _work correctly_, anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression replacement

```
myString.replace(/-.*$/, '')
```

For example

```js
var myString = 'john';

alert('"' + myString + '" becomes "' + myString.replace(/-.*$/, '') + '"');

myString = 'john-hops-over-the-candlestick';

alert('"' + myString + '" becomes "' + myString.replace(/-.*$/, '') + '"');
```

Comment: Does not work for any character as the question asks, but you could do `function breakAt(str, at){return str.replace(new RegExp(at+'.*$'), '');}`. Note that you have to use `new RegExp()` to perform concatenation to Strings when creating a RegExp.

Comment: @PHPglue true, but the question most certainly does not ask for *"any character"*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function breakAt(str, at){
  return str.split(at)[0];
}
console.log(breakAt('john-hops-over-the-candlestick', '-'));
console.log(breakAt('john-hops-over-the-candlestick', 'john'));
```

Comment: This returns 'hops-over-the-candlestick', not 'john'.

Comment: Sorry about that. I think it's fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The following `truncateAt` function should do what you want.

```js
var string1 = 'john';
var string2 = 'john-hops-over-the-candlestick';
var string3 = 'john hops over the candlestick';

function truncateAt(str, char) {
  var idx = str.indexOf(char);
  return idx === -1 ? str : str.substr(0, idx);
}

console.log(truncateAt(string1, '-'));
console.log(truncateAt(string2, '-'));
console.log(truncateAt(string3, '-'));
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for checking. But your approach was more clever and concise.

Comment: I deleted my comment because the performance benchmarks kept changing on subsequent runs but here it is again anyway :) http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-substr-with-indexof

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I temporarily added a test case for `split('-')[0]` and ran it a few times with that one too. The `split` throughput was always in the same ballpark as the other two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use split();
var str = 'john-sample';        
var substr = str.split('-');
fname = substr[0];
alert(fname);
```